# Need to analyse missing values + difference in peaks

Tags: self-study, spss

I am currently working on an analysis that compares heart rate data from multiple devices. In order to do this I recorder all the raw data in a table. Currently I am writing a script that will parse all my raw data tables.

An example of the data can be found here (date; model; datatime; BPM)

```
Sun Feb 28 17:31:24 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677084603   80
Sun Feb 28 17:31:24 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677084603   80
Sun Feb 28 17:31:24 GMT+01:00 2016  H7  1456677084915   79
Sun Feb 28 17:31:25 GMT+01:00 2016  HW  1456677085051   68
Sun Feb 28 17:31:25 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677085607   79
Sun Feb 28 17:31:25 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677085607   79
Sun Feb 28 17:31:25 GMT+01:00 2016  H7  1456677085891   79
Sun Feb 28 17:31:26 GMT+01:00 2016  HW  1456677086003   71
Sun Feb 28 17:31:26 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677086608   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:26 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677086608   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:26 GMT+01:00 2016  H7  1456677086913   80
Sun Feb 28 17:31:26 GMT+01:00 2016  HW  1456677086980   73
Sun Feb 28 17:31:27 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677087321   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:27 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677087321   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:27 GMT+01:00 2016  HW  1456677087795   75
Sun Feb 28 17:31:28 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677088607   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:28 GMT+01:00 2016  MB  1456677088607   78
Sun Feb 28 17:31:28 GMT+01:00 2016  HW  1456677088716   76
Sun Feb 28 17:31:28 GMT+01:00 2016  H7  1456677088834   80
```

1. I am trying to come up with a statistic that proves that certain values are missing. f.e. the HW model has less entries. I would like a statestic that proves how many values are actually missing and what the minimum and maximum interval is.

A graph can be found here:

[image]

2. Her You can see that the Polar has high peaks but that the Microsoft Band does not follow accordingly. I would hope to find something that helps me put that in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think calculating the trend components and cyclical components of Ploar, MB etc. time series data could help you to substantiate the difference. I see that polar has a strong cyclical component and a strong increasing trend compared to others.

Identifying the slopes using regression could also be a another way out. Just a thought!